# Delete files except those whose name matches a string

Tags: bash, grep, find

I'm trying to delete all files (include subdir) in a directory but only files which not match specific file name: "equipe" "match" "express"

I'm trying to do it with this command

```
find . -type f '!' -exec grep -q "equipe" {} \; -exec echo rm {} \;
```

1. That doesn't work. It echos files with "equipe" inside
2. How can I do it with multiple strings? ("equipe" "match" "express")

Comment: What about the files within directories that match / don't match?

Comment: i would like to delete all files who don't match all the conditions.

Comment: finally i want to have only equipe.pdf, express.pdf, lejournalduMatch.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `find`:

```
find . -type f -not \( -name '*equipe*' -o -name '*match*' -o -name '*express*' \) -delete
```

Comment: thanks !! To try it before delete everyting where could i add an echo or something to test  ?

Comment: @Nicolas just remove the `-delete` to list the files :)

Comment: it doesn't work but my description was not totally clear...sorry i'm trying to delete all files which the name not CONTAINS these 3 words...

Comment: i add a wildcard before and after and it works thanks