# How do I delete all the MP4 files with a file name not ending with -converted?

Tags: bash, zsh

I converted/compressed several MP4 files from several folders using VLC.
The names of the converted/compressed files end with -converted, for example. `2. bubble sort-converted.mp4`.

It's really cumbersome to go into each folder and delete all the original files and leave the converted files.

Using some zsh/bash command I'd like to recursively delete all the original files and leave the converted files.
For example I'll delete `3 - sorting/2. bubble sort.mp4` and will leave `3 - sorting/2. bubble sort-converted.mp4`.

**TLDR;
In easy words, delete all the files with `.mp4` extension, where filesnames don't end with `-converted` using some zsh/bash command.**

*Also If there is some way to rename the converted file to the original name after deleting the original files, that will be a plus.*

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete files except those whose name matches a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951725/delete-files-except-those-whose-name-matches-a-string)

Comment: I read the answer to that question, but I'm a noob in bash, so I don't know how to edit it for my use case. 
Thank you for the share!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` can be used with a logical expression to match the desired files and delete them.

In your case the following can be used to verify whether it matches the files you want to delete. It finds all files that don't have `converted` in their names but do end in `.mp4`.

```
find . -type f -not \( -name '*converted*' \) -a -name "*.mp4"
```

Once you are satsified with the file list result then add `-delete` to do the actual delete.

```
find . -type f -not \( -name '*converted*' \) -a -name "*.mp4" -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
find . -name '*.mp4' | grep -v 'converted' | xargs rm -f
```

Answer (score 0):

The zsh pure solution:

```
rm -f ^(*.mp4-converted)(.)

^ ................. negates
*-converted ....... pattern
(.) ............... regular files
```

Using gnu parallel (in case of many files)

```
parallel --no-notice rm -rf ::: ^(*converted)(.)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work even if your file names contain ', " or space:

```
find . -name '*.mp4' |
  grep -v 'converted' |
  parallel -X rm -f
```